# Php extract objects vars without cycling object itself

Tags: php, arrays, object, cycle, extract

hi i have this object:

```
object(stdClass)#27 (1) {
 [0]=> object(stdClass)#26 (6){
 ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#24 (1) {
 ["$id"]=> string(24) "4e6ea439caa47c2c0c000000" 
}
["username"]=> string(16) "wdfkewkghbrjkghb" ["email"]=> string(24) "wdhbfjkwhegerg@â‚¬rg.efg" ["password"]=> string(32) "4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93" ["slug"]=> string(16) "wdfkewkghbrjkghb" ["insert_datetime"]=> string(19) "2011-09-13 12:09:49" 
} 

}
```

how can i retrieve for example object->username without cycling the object?

thx

[EDITED]

this is the little piece of code i have:

```
$user = $this->model_user->populateBy($id = '12');
            var_dump($user);
            echo $user->username ; // error:Trying to get property of non-object  non object
```

doing var_dump($user); it prints out the object i pasted up.

Comment: What do you mean "cycling" the object? Doesn't `$object->username` work?

Comment: What do you mean by "cycling the object"?  Can you show the PHP code that you're using?

Comment: i guess you need to have a look at OOP reference in PHP

Comment: this object returns from a query i assign that to $user = $query_result = $object;    then if i do echo $user->username; it says error:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: while , foreach( $user as $row) { echo $row->username; }   works

Comment: no one knows what's up with this object?

Answer (score 1):

I think [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) is what you need.

I'm not sure I understand the question though; if you want the username you can just do `$Object->username`..

Comment: get_object_vars() return empty array :(